# Why am I having CORS error on uploading larger files?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors

I am using C# on .NET Core for the back-end API and Angular 6 for the front-end. When I upload a file to test on my localhost, I can upload any size file without error, but when on the production, it limits me to upload to 64KB. If the file I try to upload is larger than 64KB, it throws an error

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource
> How can this be solved?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured CORS correctly or at all, please include details on what you have done to verify that CORS is correctly configured in the production deployment. You can also show the HTTP trace of the request and response headers to demonstrate that it is working as you expect.

Comment: No, it sounds like a fake error. Chrome in particular is ergularly reporitng CORS errors when something different goes wrong on the backend and it can not figure out WHAT. Sort of a "oh - hm - no idea, let's blame CORS" attitude. Just sfinished al arge API project and we got a TON of reports from frontend people all with false CORS errors while the real error was something different.

Comment: Enable cross-domain in your request. I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow larger file size, you need to update your **Web.config** file for your API.

Under your `<system.webServer>` tag, please add the following and define the size

```
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" /> <!--2GB-->
     </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

You can set any size but make sure the **timeout** is long enough to process the request if it's a huge file otherwise the API will throw a Timeout error

the timeout can be set in web.config also as following

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" executionTimeout="9999" maxRequestLength="2000000" /> <!--approx 2GB-->
```

For more information please see the following

https://forums.asp.net/post/6084972.aspx

https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much, when i add size setting in web.config file, it work perfectly

Comment: no worries, If this resolved your problem, please make this as an answer